# Error Mysql - Subconsulta devuelve mas de una fila

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas:

Tabla 1 - Usuarios:

- codigo_usuario(PK)
- nombre
- apellido
- fecha_nacimiento
- sexo_usuario
- direccion_domicilio
- estado_civil
- numero_celular
- pais_residencia
- foto_usuario

Tabla 2 - Usuarios Cuentas:

- codigo_cuenta(PK)
- codigo_usuario(FK)
- correo_electronico
- clave_cuenta

Conociendo los valores de nombre, apellido, fecha_nacimiento y sexo trato de obtener como resultado una tabla con las siguientes columnas:

Tabla Resultado:

- codigo_cuenta
- correo_electronico
- nombre
- apellido
- numero_celular
- foto_usuario

Las dos primeras columnas serian de la tabla `Usuarios Cuentas` y las cuatro ultimas serian de la tabla `Usuarios`, para ello hize la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT codigo_cuenta, 
       correo_electronico, 
       nombre, 
       apellido, 
       numero_celular, 
       foto_usuario 
FROM usuarios, usuarios_cuentas 
WHERE codigo_usuario= (SELECT codigo_usuario FROM usuarios 
                       WHERE nombre = 'nombre' AND apellido = 'apellido' 
                       AND fecha_nacimiento = '1995-07-25' 
                       AND sexo_usuario = 'Masculino')
```

Pero esa consulta me devuelve un error de que en la subconsulta hay mas de una fila. Luego investigando un poco me di cuenta que no puedo comparar un valor con un conjunto de valores que devuelve la subconsulta, entonces transforme la consulta a la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT codigo_cuenta, 
       correo_electronico, 
       nombre, apellido, 
       numero_celular, 
       foto_usuario 
FROM usuarios, usuarios_cuentas 
WHERE codigo_usuario IN (SELECT codigo_usuario FROM usuarios 
                         WHERE nombre RLIKE 'nombre' 
                         AND apellido RLIKE 'apellido' 
                         AND fecha_nacimiento = '1995-07-25' 
                         AND sexo_usuario = 'Masculino')
```

Esto básicamente funciona pero hay un problema, y es de que por cada registro que haya en la tabla me lo devuelve repetido 3 veces intercalados con otros registros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que para tu segunda columna podemos eliminar los duplicados si al inicio del `SELECT` justo antes de invocar a la primer columna usamos `DISTINCT` de este modo

```
SELECT DISTINCT codigo_cuenta, 
        correo_electronico, 
        nombre, apellido, 
        numero_celular, 
        foto_usuario
```

.Aunque igual por la sintaxis que veo tal vez lo que más conviene es el uso de un `JOIN` de este modo

```
SELECT  codigo_cuenta, 
        correo_electronico, 
        nombre, apellido, 
        numero_celular, 
        foto_usuario
FROM usuarios 
JOIN usuarios_cuentas ON usuarios.codigo_usuario = usuarios_cuentas.codigo_usuario
WHERE nombre RLIKE 'nombre' 
AND apellido RLIKE 'apellido' 
AND fecha_nacimiento = '1995-07-25' 
AND sexo_usuario = 'Masculino';
```

> Lo anterior por qué veo que usas una sintaxis un tanto obsoleta, además si la intención es obtener datos de dos tablas relacionadas lo logras por medio de join que solo considera los datos de la izquierda que existen en la tabla de la derecha